# catch a deliberately generated error by stop() inside a function in a tryCatch

Tags: r, mocking, try-catch, testthat

```
fn2 <- function(args2){
    output
}

fn1 <- function(arg1){
            tryCatch({
                output = do.call(fn2, args2_list)
            }, error = function(e){
                if(str_detect(e$message, 'err_msg', negate = FALSE)){
                    <do something> 
                }
                stop(e$message)   
            })
        }
```

I have some code structured as shown above. `fn2` gives an error but is not reproducible as of now. I only know what the error message is. So I have placed a `tryCatch` to capture the error and check if it's the same message for which I need to get more context and do some handling for it. 
But I need to write a test using `testthat` which tests that when the error message is returned it only does the handling if the string match is correct else does not. How can I do so?
 It seems I need to mock `fn2` and return the error message which gets caught by the `tryCatch` block. I tried using `stop('err_msg')` in the mock function but it is not caught by the `tryCatch` block it seems.

Comment: In case you do not get your processed error, my understanding is that a) error did not occur or b) the error is of a different type than what you expect. For b) you would need to write another handler within your `function(e)` function.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik If I understand correctly what you are saying is that stop() should have generated the error which should have been caught by the tryCatch block?

Comment: It's not clear to me if stop should be called within the error handling function of `tryCatch`. I would first try to handle all cases of the error message gracefully, though.